# What are the considerations when submitting an app to Apple that requires a credit card to create an order and use half the functionality

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I'll be submitting my app to Apple for review at the end of the week. The app is a marketplace platform so users need to enter a credit card when creating an order.

In order for Apple to test the app I assume they need to go through every screen but a credit card is needed for to get to most of them. I'm using Stripe for payment processing and have a dummy card I use for testing, but when I switch to the live environment I don't think the dummy card works any more so how can I allow apple to test it?

I can't figure out how I can submit a production ready app with live API keys and let apple test without processing a real order and charging a real card.

Comment: They definitely do not go through every screen, and they definitely won't make an order for a physical product or real-life service. Of course, anything that is provided directly in/via the app should go through IAPs.